# white blank displayed on webpage occasionally when changing the select option value

Tags: php, html, css, jquery

I am building an online system where the users are instructors of a certain college institution. One of the main function of the system is for the users to be able to view their schedules via internet.

I am currently building the page where the users view their schedule, and what I have done is create a select option in it that triggers a jquery function (that does an ajax request) when the value is changed. The requested page is then displayed on a div in the current page.

The problem is, when I try to change the value of a select option, the page occasionally displays a huge white blank on top of my whole page. I don't know what triggers the bug since it only happens occasionally, not every time. When i reload the page, the white space disappears.

I have been searching for answers everywhere and did not get one that fits my problem.

This is the page before the white space shows up
https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-rb0XXjcpn6w/UPiwjIY92OI/AAAAAAAAABo/BmiDIbZWcxU/s640/before.jpg

This is the page when the white space shows up
https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-RZxh2P3Bk0o/UPiwRv5oHHI/AAAAAAAAABc/VIB6LYvPBE4/s640/after.jpg

I hope you guys can help me out...

this is the code of the page..

```
<?php
require_once("../includes/initialize.php");

 $adminEmps = employee::find_by_cond("(department = 'ACADEMIC-TEACHING' or department = 'ACADEMIC-NON TEACHING') and emp_status='active' order by lastname asc");

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"         "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Schedule</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function selectEmp(){
$('#here').html("<img src=../Images/gif/loading14.gif' class='three columns     centered'>");
$.post('viewSched.php','id='+$('#selector').val()+'&yr='+$('#yrselect').val(),
    function (response){
      $('#here').html(response);
    });
}
</script>
<body>
<?php include("AdminDropdown.php"); ?>
<div class="row">
 <div class="twelve columns">
<div class="row panel">
    <h2><img src="../Images/Shedule.png" height="100px" width="100px" style="vertical-align:middle"/>
        Schedule
    </h2>
    <dl class="tabs pill">
      <dd class="active"><a href="#simple1">Academic</a></dd>
      <dd><a href="#simple2">Administrative</a></dd>
      <dd class="hide-for-small"><a href="#simple3">OSAS</a></dd>
    </dl>
  </div>
 <ul class="tabs-content">
<li class="active" id="simple1Tab">
<div class="two columns">
  Select Employee 
</div>
<div class="three columns end">
  <select id='selector' onchange="selectEmp()" >
    <option>--Select--</option>
   <?php
    foreach ($adminEmps as $key => $value) {
      echo "<option value={$value['emp_ID']}>{$value['lastName']},     {$value['firstName']} {$value['lastName']}</option>";
    }
   ?>
  </select>
</div>
<div class='two columns'>
</div>
<div class='two columns' style='text-align:right;'>
  Select Year
</div>
<div class='three columns end'>
  <select id='yrselect' onchange="selectEmp()">
    <option>-- Select --</option>
    <?php
      for ($i=2008; $i <= date('Y'); $i++) { 
        $yr = $i + 1;
        echo "<option>{$i}-{$yr}</option>";
      }
    ?>
  </select>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div class="twelve columns ">
  <div class="nine columns centered">
    <div id='here'>

  </div>
  </div>
</div>

</li>
<li id="simple2Tab"></li>
<li id="simple3Tab">This is simple tab 3s content.</li>
</ul>   

</div>
</div>


<?php include("adminfooter.php"); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is the code of the requested page.

```
<?php
require_once('../includes/initialize.php');

    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $yr = $_POST['yr'];
        $info = sched::find_scheds_by_id_yr($id,$yr);
        $display = "<table>
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Day</th>
                            <th>Time Start</th>
                            <th>Time End</th>
                            <th>Room</th>
                            <th>Subject</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>

                        ";
                    if($info){
        foreach ($info as $key2 => $value2) {
            $display .= "<tr>
                        <td>".$value2['day']."</td>
                        <td> ".$value2['time_start']."</td>
                        <td>{$value2['time_end']}</td>
                        <td>{$value2['room']}</td>
                        <td>{$value2['Subject_description']}</td>
                        </tr>";
        }
    }
            $display.="</tbody>
                    </table>";


?>
<html>
<head><title></title></head>
<body>
    <?php echo $display; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

By the way this only happens in google chrome.

Comment: This seems to be a problem affecting your HTML markup (i.e., that white box is a DOM element). There's no way we could help without looking at your HTML/JS.

Comment: ive just pasted my codes..

Comment: are you still there? please help me out... I'm on a deadline..

Answer (score 0):

Going by your source files, the only javascript visible changes the content of the `#here` `div`, to a loading image inside an `img` tag, or to the result of the AJAX call.

Since nothing but this `div` seems to be changing, you should take a look at the css and see if its correctly handling a `div` with dynamic content (i.e, a `div` whose contents will be changing in size).

Look for how it's being positioned/sized, and how you're handling the `overflow` property.

Comment: is there something I should consider changing or adding to it?

Comment: No. I do not see anything within what you've shown that would cause that `div` to jump out of place, or any other modification to the DOM. I'd try setting `overflow:hidden` and a fixed `width` and `height` to see if it helps debugging the issue.

Comment: thank u so much for your help.. I'm new here and you're the first person to help me here, and obviously the only one who cared.So I Appreciate it so much..

Comment: hey I tried setting the width and height to a fixed size and overflow to hidden.. it seems to have stopped the white space from appearing. now my only problem is I have to keep my div dynamic because there is no certain value of the content to appear. Plus, I don't even know what causes my div to relocate like that, or if its even whats happening.

Comment: Have you tried adding the css float:left; clear:both; to the offending div?